# Best practice when using an API key in Node.js

Tags: node.js, api-key

I have an API key I'm using in my Node.js application. Currently, I keep it stored in a text file and put it in a global variable when my application starts up.

So basically it's just:

```
var key = getKey();
useKeyGetData(key);
```

I don't like having this global variable, and it's a pain to pass between files. Is there a better way to get my key where/when I need it? Is there some standard for doing so?

Comment: What's wrong with saving it in a .js file and exporting the values? Then you can just require them where you need it.

Comment: apparently, i don't understand your question. if you don't want it globally require it locally.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The conventional alternative to what you're doing, especially when pertaining to API keys, is to use [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). This is an operating system-level configuration facility. Each process has its own set of environment variables, usually inherited from its parent process. By convention, environment variables have uppercase names.

In node.js, you can access environment variables through [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). For example, if you run an application like this:

```
$ MY_VARIABLE=test node app.js
```

You can access the value of the `MY_VARIABLE` environment variable via:

```
process.env.MY_VARIABLE
```

It can be tedious, however, to have to keep passing the environment variable(s) on each invocation of your program. That's why there are packages such as [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) which allow you to store your environment variables in a text file.

More specifically, you will have a file called `.env` and in it you might have:

```
MY_VARIABLE=test
OTHER_VARIABLE=foo
```

At the beginning of your `app.js`, you then do:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

This reads the environment variable values from the `.env` file. You can then access them as you would access any other environment variables:

```
console.log("MY_VARIABLE: " + process.env.MY_VARIABLE);
console.log("OTHER_VARIABLE: " + process.env.OTHER_VARIABLE);
```

Now you don't have to explicitly pass the environment variables to your application upon invocation, i.e. you can just run it as usual:

```
$ node app.js
```

If you *do* pass one explicitly, it will override whatever value you gave in your `.env` file:

```
$ MY_VARIABLE=bar node app.js
```

Now the `MY_VARIABLE` environment variable will have a value of `"bar"` instead of `"testing"`. Since `OTHER_VARIABLE` isn't passed explicitly, it retains its value of `"foo"` specified in the `.env` file.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Exactly what I was looking for: standard conventions for handling my key.

Comment: I am trying to make sense why this is a good sense. I am planning to use dotenv for production nodejs server, but want to understand how is this file better than lets say a ```contants.json``` file or npm config module? Can you please explain what is the security/benefit of passing credentials via environment variables?

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, don't confuse dotenv with environment variables themselves. dotenv is simply an npm package that makes it easier to work with them by supporting the use of a file where you can specify env vars. The file is a convenience; it's not what environment variables themselves are about. The advantage of env vars over an arbitrary constants.json file is that it's the standard way of configuring processes. Docker, systemd, upstart, etc. all understand this way of configuring multiple _separate_ instances of a process.

Comment: For example, say you want to spawn multiple instances of a server process, each bound to different ports. If you use a constants.json file, you have to implement support for having separate constants.json files per-process or something. With env vars, this is natural, you simply spawn multiple instances with a different env var: `$ PORT=3000 myprocess`, `$ PORT=3001 myprocess`, etc. In production you usually specify these env vars in the process manager you use like systemd, upstart, docker, or a wrapper script.

Comment: Another benefit is that this is an operating-system level mechanism. Any part of your process can access these environment variables, even child processes spawned by your process inherit the variables by default; they don't each have to implement support for reading your custom configuration file, they simply read the environment variable, regardless of the language they're written in.

Comment: Finally, they are not a silver bullet. It's not an all or nothing situation. You may yet have a configuration file (it may make more sense) for more general settings and you can check for env vars to see if they should override certain settings on a per-process basis, or you may forego env vars entirely. It's up to you, it's simply another way of doing things.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña, thanks. What about another approach: create a secretKeys.js file (gitignore it), and import keys from this file whenever needed in another file? According to your comments above, it seems to be quite good as well?

Comment: This is very good, although it would still be worthwhile to note that another best practice is including the .env file in your .gitignore so it doesn't get shown to the entire public due to security reasons.